# AngularJS - Directive populates textbox but ng-model doesn't have the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a textbox with a directive attached. This custom directive opens a modal with a form that assists the user in looking up a value from an internal company API.

The form populates the textbox with the selected value. That works exactly as expected.  Next to the textbox, there is a button that fires a function.

Currently, the function is only firing an `alert` that shows the value of the textbox based on the `ng-model` name.  The alert always shows `undefined` when using the form to populate the value in the textbox.

However, manually typing in a value works and so does using jQuery to find the value.  Any idea why the model isn't reporting the value change and how to fix it?

```
<input 
    id="txtAlias" 
    ng-model="sac.newUser" 
    type="text" 
    user-search />
<input 
    id="btnAdd" 
    type="button" 
    value="Add User" 
    class="btn btn-success btn-sm"
    ng-click="sac.AddUser()" />
```

And here is the controller's `AddUser` function:

```
sac.AddUser = function () {
    //alert($('#txtAlias').val());
    alert(sac.newUser);
}
```

As I said, the jQuery version finds the value with no problem when it was inserted into the textbox with the modal popup form.  The angular model binding will not find the textbox value when inserted using the modal popup form but it will when a value is manually typed into the textbox.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show your directive?

Comment: Shashank:  The directive isn't the issue.  It's working as expected.  The issue is that the text being dropped by the directive into the textbox isn't being recognized by the parent model when using angular to detect the value.  However, the value is being recognized by jQuery.

Comment: Yes @johneasley that is why I asked you to show your directive because jQuery simply works on DOM elements while Angular creates its own structure for models. So, jQuery can easily read your value in your textbox while there should be some problem with your directive.

Comment: @ShashankAgrawal  Okay, I understand.  Unfortunately, the directive is too long (by 2600 characters) to post in a comment so I'll try posting it in a reply to the original message.

Answer (score 0):

By request, here is the content of the original directive:

```
angular
.module('app')
.controller('userSearchModal', userSearchModal)
.directive('userSearch', userSearch);

function userSearch($compile, $uibModal) {

return {
    scope: {
        show: "="
    },
    controller: function ()
    {
        this.myusersearch = function (el) {

            var modal = $uibModal.open({
                animation: true,
                templateUrl: 'views/userSearchView.html',
                controller: 'userSearchModal',
                controllerAs: 'm',
                size: 'lg'
            });

            modal
                .result
                .then(function (selectedalias) {
                    $(el).val(selectedalias);
                });

        };

    },
    controllerAs: 'u',

    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        element.bind('focus', function () {

            var nextElement = element.parent().find('.openuserdialog').length;

            if (nextElement === 0) {

                var btn = '<img src="' + homePath + 'Images/zoomHS.png" ' +
                            'ng-click="u.myusersearch(&quot;#' + attrs.id + '&quot;)" ' +
                            'class="openuserdialog" />';

                element.after($compile(btn)(scope));

            }

        });

    }

};

};

userSearchModal.$inject = ['$uibModalInstance', '$http'];

function userSearchModal($uibModalInstance, $http) {

var modal = this;
var baseUrl = homePath + 'api/UserSearch/';
var getUrl = baseUrl + 'Get?firstname=';

modal.searching = false;
modal.progress = 'Searching...';
modal.showresults = false;

modal.search = function () {
    //Show the Searching... panel
    modal.searching = true;

    //Use the criteria to run a search
    $http.get(getUrl + modal.firstname + '&lastname=' + modal.lastname + '&alias=' + modal.alias)
        .success(function (data) {
            modal.users = data;
            modal.searching = false;
            modal.showresults = true;

            if (data.length === 0) {
                modal.progress = 'No employees found for those search parameters.';
                modal.searching = true;
                modal.showresults = false;
            }

            if (data.length > 29) {
                modal.progress = 'More than 30 employees were returned.  Please refine your search parameters.';
                modal.searching = true;
            }
        })
        .error(function (error) {
            toastr.danger(msgErrorOnGet + 'UserSearchController:  ' + error.message);
            modal.searching = false;
            modal.showresults = false;
        });

};

modal.select = function (u) {
    $uibModalInstance.close(u.Alias);
};

modal.cancel = function () {
    modal.firstname = '';
    modal.lastname = '';
    modal.alias = '';
    modal.mySearchForm.$setPristine();
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss();
};
};
```